# How to avoid jruby's Bad File Descriptor on openssl?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, net-http, jruby-openssl

I'm in a java swing application which has its WebService client implemented in jruby.
The use case is User clicks on a button, the corresponding controller opens a new Thread and this thread takes a list from a local DB and for each item of the list runs a jruby script (through ScriptingContainer).

Always the first 2 or 3 calls that jruby does succeed, but then it throws:

```
org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (Errno::EBADF) Bad file descriptor
at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedEvalUnitImpl.run(EmbedEvalUnitImpl.java:133)
at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runUnit(ScriptingContainer.java:1264)
at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet(ScriptingContainer.java:1309)
at com.doctrans.AteaService.createMsgAndSend(AteaService.java:112)
at com.doctrans.AteaService.communicateTransportation(AteaService.java:85)
at com.doctrans.DocTransFacadeImpl.requestAteaCode(DocTransFacadeImpl.java:308)
at com.doctrans.DocTransFacadeImpl.requestAteaLoadStockCodes(DocTransFacadeImpl.java:132)
at com.doctrans.gui.controllers.RoutesCtrl$RequestTask.doInBackground(RoutesCtrl.java:501)
at com.doctrans.gui.controllers.RoutesCtrl$RequestTask.doInBackground(RoutesCtrl.java:1)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (Errno::EBADF) Bad file descriptor
at org.jruby.RubyIO.close(org/jruby/RubyIO.java:2052)
at org.jruby.ext.openssl.SSLSocket.sysclose(org/jruby/ext/openssl/SSLSocket.java:704)
at RUBY.close(jar:file:C:/DocTrans/data/DocTrans-2013.10.07.14.45.jar!/openssl/buffering.rb:447)
at RUBY.close(jar:file:C:/DocTrans/data/DocTrans-2013.10.07.14.45.jar!/net/protocol.rb:76)
at RUBY.transport_request(jar:file:C:/DocTrans/data/DocTrans-2013.10.07.14.45.jar!/net/http.rb:1338)
at RUBY.request(jar:file:C:/DocTrans/data/DocTrans-2013.10.07.14.45.jar!/net/http.rb:1301)
at RUBY.send_envio_documento_transporte(jar:file:C:/DocTrans/data/DocTrans-2013.10.07.14.45.jar!/pt/atea/client.rb:81)
at RUBY.(root)(send_request_for_app.rb:50)
```

Here is the code which is iterated for each item:

```
public String createMsgAndSend(RouteInfo routeInfo) throws IOException {
    ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer(LocalContextScope.CONCURRENT);
    String code = null;
    try {
        container.put("info", new Info());
        container.put("route_info", routeInfo);
        container.put("logger", LoggerFactory.getLogger("RubyClient"));
        container.put("user", UserHolder.getCurrentUser()
                .getUser());
        container.put("pwd", UserHolder.getCurrentUser().getPwd());
        RubyObject response = (RubyObject) container.runScriptlet(
                PathType.CLASSPATH, "send_request_for_app.rb");
        Ruby ruby = container.getRuntime();
        boolean success = response.callMethod("fetch",
                RubySymbol.newSymbol(ruby, "success")).isTrue();
        LOGGER.info("Success?: " + success);
        String error = (String) response.callMethod("fetch",
                RubySymbol.newSymbol(ruby, "error")).asJavaString();
        if (success && error.isEmpty()) {
            code = (String) response.callMethod("fetch",
                    RubySymbol.newSymbol(ruby, "code")).asJavaString();
            LOGGER.info("Response code: " + code);
        } else {
            throw new ServiceException(routeInfo, error);
        }
    } finally {
        if (container != null) {
            container.resetWriter();
            container.resetErrorWriter();
            container.clear();
            container.terminate();
        }
    }
    return code;
}
```

The jruby net/http code which is throwing exception:

```
      http= Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
      http.use_ssl = true
      http.ssl_version = 'SSLv3'
      http.open_timeout= 5000
      http.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(pem)
      http.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(pem, pem_key)
      http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
      request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
      http.finish if http.started?
```

I suspect that this may be related to java threads, but don't know where the problem is.
How can I avoid this Bad file descriptor exception?

Comment: Some time ago I had this very same error with jruby. I also got the "bad file descriptor" exception.
It was a swing app with a thread that runs the jruby script, I put a sleep after calling jruby to allow the closing of the script connections but the problem persisted.
At the end we implemented everything in pure java. Good luck!

Comment: Tried to add a sleep of 2sec. after container.terminate but the error still occurs.

Comment: Also did the same call from a test class without threads which repeats the same call to the container 10 times and there it works..

Comment: Also tried using LocalContextScope.CONCURRENT at ScriptingContainer constructor, and running each call to createMsgAndSend in a separate thread with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

I answer my own question:
It was a bug in the openssl lib. Asked in the jruby mailing list and they recomended to upgrade.
Upgrading to JRuby 1.7.5 solved the problem!